# Is the Chrome OS Files app available to install on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, chromebook, chromeos

I was wondering if there was a way to install the Chrome OS (Chromebook) Files app on my Ubuntu Disco system without having to build it from source?

[image: https://news-cdn.softpedia.com/images/news2/chrome-os-files-app-redesigned-with-support-for-viewing-android-and-linux-files-521982-2.jpg] (Image URL: https://news-cdn.softpedia.com/images/news2/chrome-os-files-app-redesigned-with-support-for-viewing-android-and-linux-files-521982-2.jpg)

I personally prefer how the Files app on Chrome only has a Downloads folder instead of Documents/Music/Pictures/Videos/Public/etc. etc. etc. like Nautilus, Nemo, and almost every other "Linux" file manager I can think of.

Even if it doesn't work well with Ubuntu (I'm thinking the folders "Play files" and "Linux files" might not work when I click on them?), it would still be nice to know that there is an option to install it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you want it *only* because it has a "Downloads folder instead of Documents/Music/Pictures/Videos/Public/etc."? You can remove other folders from Nautilus et al. if you wish.

Comment: I actually tried that before in Nautilus but I would prefer the layout of the Files.